# Looking for a solution to decoding full HD JPEG images in about 6-7 ms each using Metal shaders

Tags: ios, metal, metal-performance-shaders

I have a **1080p** image, encoded as `JPEG`.
I want to load to an `MTLTexture`, but using `MTKTextureLoader` it takes about **~60 ms**.

I need a solution to **decode** it under **6-7 ms**. And yes, It needed to achieve 30 FPS while rendering with `MetalView`

I already tried GPU supported image format, but it makes huge, uncompressed files which is unacceptable for me.

Comment: Question is unclear regarding encode or decode.

Comment: @hotpaw2 thank you, fixed it

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @0xBFE1A8 I updated the question and tried to improve the quality of it also. Thank you.